# Fetching relations with Core Data

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, nsfetchrequest

I have two managed objects which have a bidirectional relationship.
It is a 'segmentWithDetails' which contains a 'segment' object.

I use

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SegmentWithDetails" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:connectionDetailsService.connectionDetailsContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

to get my segmentWith Details. This works ok.

BUT, when I try to retrieve the contained segment, I get nil.

I've tried to get it with

```
Segment *segment = [segmentWithDetails valueForKeyPath:@"segment"];
```

and with

```
Segment *segment = segmentWithDetails.segment;
```

But this does not work (=nil). I've also tried modifying the NSFetchedResultsController.
I added the following:

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"segment"]];
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:YES];
```

But both of these do not seem to make any difference.
From what I understand out of Apple fine documentation, the relationship should just work using faults.

What am I missing here?
How do I get to the relationship object 'segment' from 'segmentWithDetails' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was not how I read the data, but how I put it in CoreData.
The posted code above is indeed correct. Thanx for the response Jaanus.

Comment: just FYI - you can comment on answers

Answer (score 4):

It should just work like you describe. Are you sure the "segment" object/relation actually exists and contains a real object? Check the data model that this relation isn't optional and check your code that you have actually stored something.

Comment: Yep, they have an exisisting relation.
I use a SOAP Webservice to fill them with data. No problem there.
I can also change the fetchedResultsController to switch between segmentWithDetails & segment.

But I am unable to get from segment to the parent segmentWithDetails or vica versa.

I re-use the NSManagedObjectContext out of the object I used to fill the objects with data.
Could that be an issue?